# Symfony2/Doctrine: How to load only related objects for current logged in user?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

My Symfony2 application displays songs and lets the user rate them. User Management is done with FOSUserBundle.
I have defined an One-To-Many Relationship between two Objects (Song & Ratings) defined like this:

*Entity/Song.php*

```
/**
 * Song
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="[...]\[...]Bundle\Entity\SongRepository")
 */
class Song
{
[...]
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Rating", mappedBy="song")
     */
    protected $ratings;
[...]
}
```

and

*Entity/Rating.php*

```
/**
 * Rating
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Rating
{
[...]
    /**
     * @var float
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="rating", type="float")
     */
    private $rating;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="[...]\UserBundle\Entity\User", inversedBy="ratings")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $user;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Song", inversedBy="ratings")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="song_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE")
     */
    protected $song;
[...]
```

When loading all the songs (~40) in my application I can access them in the controller like this:

*SongsController.php:*

```
$songs = $em->getRepository('[...]Bundle:Song')->findAll();
```

**Now, how can I efficiently make sure that I only get the rating of the currently logged in user, without iterating through all ratings and validating the user?**

*index.html.twig*:

```
{% for rating in song.ratings %}
  {% if rating.user == app.user%}
    {{ rating.rating }}
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

**EDIT:**

I have this now:

```
public function getAllSongsWithRatings($user)
{
    $qb = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder()
       ->select('s')
       ->from('[...]Bundle:Song','s')
       ->join('s.ratings','r')
       ->where('r.user = :user')
       ->setParameter('user', $user);

    return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
```

}

But when I look what doctrine generates:

```
SELECT s0_.id AS id0, s0_.number [...] FROM Song s0_ LEFT JOIN Rating [...] WHERE r1_.user_id = ? AND [...]
SELECT t0.id AS id1, t0.rating AS [...] FROM Rating t0 WHERE t0.song_id = ?
```

It does not query for the rating, including the user_id... I think this is possibly imperformant...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will want to use a repository function:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#custom-repository-classes

Then we have to get a little primative to run a native MySQL query:

```
public function getSongsWithUserRatings($userid)
{
    $stmt = $this->_em->getConnection()->executeQuery(
        'SELECT * FROM Song s LEFT JOIN Rating r ON r.song = s.song_id AND r.user = :userid',
        array('userid'=>$userid),
        array('userid'=>'integer')
    );
    return $stmt->fetchAll();
```

**Notice the leftJoin part. Using the WITH parameter will give you all the songs plus join that ratings IF they exists only from that user.**

Then in your controller you call for this and pass that along to twig:

```
//Controller

$userRatedSongs = $em->getRepository('Bundle:Songs')->getSongsWithUserRatings($this->getUser()->getUserId())
```

Then your twig template:

```
{% for song in songs %}
<h3>{{song.name}}</h3>
    {% if song.rating != null %}
    <p> Rating: {{song.rating}}</p>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

song.ratings will still be an array but if you have constraints on your ratings so that a user can only rate a song once then the first rating will be that users rating.

Comment: Thanks, I tried that, but it seems doctrine is not building the query correctly. Please see my edit above...

Comment: Let me run a quick test and ill get back to you with a working answer.

Comment: Also the problem is, that the (left) join, will return no songs in the case there are no ratings yet... I simply do not know how to design this the best way... Thanks so much!

Comment: Sorry that took so long, have a look at the revised repository function. The join now has a WITH clause. Took me a bit to find that. Now you will have all the songs and only ratings from a given user.

Comment: Ok, I changed it like you suggested, the join works, even songs without ratings show up. But Doctrine still generates this query: 
"SELECT t0.id AS id1, t0.rating AS [...] FROM Rating t0 WHERE t0.song_id = ?"
How can I achieve that the WHERE clause also takes the user_id into consideration? Doctrine generates this query when populating the ArrayCollection ratings automatically...

Comment: Im sorry i dont understand what you are asking for. Are you still not able to access the user ratings for the song?

Comment: Yes I am able to access the user ratings, but it still retrieves all ratings, also the ones from the other users...

Comment: OK, we went full native i couldnt get the `LEFT JOIN ... ON ... AND ...` to work with the query builder. This should just give you what you want. You can change the select fields if you only need some of them.

Comment: I finally got it to work, with the help of this guy: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22090393/symfony-doctrine-querybuilder-join-with-not-filtering-out-rows/22090942?noredirect=1#22090942

Comment: Thanks for your effort... Your answer actually works too, it only gives me an array...